# Split-dns based on subnet with windows server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, split-dns

I have a question about split-dns in Windows Server 2016.

I've configured DNS in Windows Server 2016. It has three interfaces: 10.x.x.x, 192.x.x.x and 110.x.x.x.

I've tried to configure DNS so that if I do a ping from a 10.x.x.x HOST  to Windows Server, it only response 10.x.x.x IP (not as Round Robbin as now).

Right now if I do a ping from host to server, first time I've got 10.x.x.x IP, second time I've got 192.x.x.x IP and third time I've got 110.x.x.x IP. 
I'm looking for the same response always depends on the subnet that comes the request.

```
Add-DnsServerClientSubnet -Name "AllowedSubnet01" -IPv4Subnet 10.0.0.0/8 -PassThru

Add-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name "WhitelistAllowedSubnet” -Action IGNORE -ClientSubnet  "NE, AllowedSubnet01" -PassThru
```

But it didn't work.

Any idea what ?

Thanks in advance!